# Schedule command on Avaya Ethernet Routing Switch 4524GT

Tags: backups, avaya

I'm trying to do some network monitoring and discovered an older network device which escaped everyone's attention. Through the CLI, I can copy my config to a tftp server but I was wondering if it was possible to schedule this task?

I'm far from fluent in Avaya Nortel and the only things I find have something to do with the GUI. Apart from the fact that I don't have those options, I rather not use the web interface because it is quite buggy. Note: only telnet is enabled and I can't enable SSH through the web gui..

The switch information:

```
sysDescr: Ethernet Routing Switch 4524GT
          HW:08       FW:5.1.0.8   SW:v5.4.0.008
```

Comment: I don't really understand the need to do this on a schedule. You copy the configuration before and after you make a change. There is no need to copy it unless a change is made. It's not like a server where there are a bunch of people adding and changing data all the time.

Comment: That's why I want to use it, so I have a copy from the configuration before any changes have been made. Let's just say we've had our fair share of problems with people who changed stuff without having a backup

Comment: That's why you only do it when you have authorized changes, so you are not backing up unauthorized changes. Backing it up on a scheduled backs up the bad changes, which seems pointless and dangerous. You could probably set up some type of SNMP event to track when changes are made.

Comment: I do think you're right btw, but history has proven that here are changes executed without authorization. I don't want to make this a yes/no discussion since that is not the main issue of the question. The question is if it is possible to schedule any command/task

Comment: "_history has proven that here are changes executed without authorization._" I understand, but my question is why do you want to back up unauthorized changes? It would seem that you only want to back up the authorized changes so that you can revert to them, rather than revert to a problem change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to backup the configuration is with CLI commands. The switch has no "cron" capability. And as I recall, v5 software doesn't have an ASCII configuration -- tftp gives you a binary blob. `show running-config` will provide a text configuration, but v5 is rather dumb and includes a mountain of defaults.

You'll need an external script to telnet into the switch and collect the output of `show running-config`.

[ssh isn't available because you aren't running the export-restricted "crypto" image.]

Answer (score 0):

As Ricky Beam said you don't have a cron job on the switch. However the assumption that tftp gives a binary blob isn't exactly correct. You have the following options to fetch the information:

> copy running-config tftp [verbose] address {A.B.C.D | } filename

command will download the **ASCII** config to TFTP. On the newer versions you also have copy-running config sftp which is only available on SSH images.

> copy config tftp address {A.B.C.D | }

will download the **binary** version of the config on the TFTP server

So you have both choices ASCII or binary.

Now, since you only have telnet, one way of doing this would be to write an Expect script (Expect is a subset of TCL) in a linux console. Expect is a pretty nice way of testing telnet/SSH text output as it allows you to send a command and to expect a certain outcome. You can send the telnet login command from TCL and "expect" the ERS 4524GT CLI prompt. Then you send the copy running-config command and save the ASCII config.
Now, if you are on a linux server you can add a cron job to run the TCL Expect script at a certain time interval depending on your needs.